# Given $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix such that $\text{det}(A) =9$, and $A^3 A^T = 3A^{-1}$ — find n.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Can anyone solve this? Thanks in advance

I tried something and the answer agrees with one given on the answer key.

$$\det (A^3 A^T) = \det (3A^{-1} \text{adj} A)$$

and since $\det A ^3 = 9 ^4$ and $\det A^t = \det A$ then

$$(\det A)^4 = 3^n \det (A^-1) \det \left( \text{adj} A \right) $$

since $\det A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}$ and

$\det \left(\text{adj} A \right)= (\det A)^{n-1}$ then

$$(\det A)^4 = \frac{3^{n}}{9} \times 9^{n-1}$$

then solved for $n$ using exponent laws to obtain $n=4 $

$$9^4= 3^n \times 9^{n-1}$$

$$3^{10}= 3^n \times 3^ {2n-1}$$

$$3^{10}= 3^n \times 3^{2n-2}$$

$$10=3n-2$$

$$12=3n$$

$$4=n$$

Does this look correct? 
Thank you!

Comment: Remember that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ that $\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}$ and that $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$

Comment: @Ali.a Maybe the following reasoning is better. $A^4A^T=3E$. Thus, $9^4\cdot9=3^n$

Answer (score 4):

$9^3\cdot9=3^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{9}$,
which gives $n=10$.

Comment: I added a solution that i tried which gives n=4 which agrees with the answer in answer key